# (React Context Beginner) React Context doesn't stat when changing page using react-rooter-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-context, state-management

I'm trying to improve my state management skill so I chose to use **REACT CONTEXT**. I am getting item data from my backend server using axios and storing it in the context.

When I am in `/home` everything works properly: state updates then component rerenders and everything looks ok. But when I move to `/shop` and I `console.log(items)` it returns me an empty array instead of data that I got just before.

Here are my files:

**APP.JS**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './components/navigations/NavBAr/Nav';
import HeaderSlides from './components/slides/header/HeaderSlide';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Logs/Login/Login';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ItemProvider } from './context/ItemContext';
import Register from './components/Logs/Register/Register';
import { UserProvider } from './context/UserContext';
import Shop from './components/Shop/Shop';



function App() {

  return (
    <ItemProvider>
      <UserProvider>
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <Nav/>
      </header>
      <Route render={({ location }) => (
            <Switch location={location}>
              <Route exact path='/' render={ () => (<Home/>)}/>
              <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
              <Route path='/register' component={Register}/>
              <Route path='/shop' component={Shop}/>
            </Switch>
      )} />
      <footer>
        <Footer/>
      </footer>
    </div>
    </UserProvider>
    </ItemProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ItemContext**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ItemContext = createContext();

export function ItemProvider(props) {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);


    return (
        <ItemContext.Provider value={[items, setItems]}>
            {props.children}
        </ItemContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**Item.js ** call in Home.js context work

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';

//styles
import './Items.css'

//items
import { ItemContext } from '../../../../context/ItemContext'

export default function Items({ toShow }) {

    const [items, setItems] = useContext(ItemContext);
    const data = items
    let stuff;
    if (data.length === 0) {
        console.log("loading");
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        stuff = data.map((details, i) => {
            const { name, brand, gender, price, image, categorie } = details;
            while (gender === toShow) {
                return (
                    <div id="itemCard1">
                        <div className="itemImgWrap">
                            <img src={image} alt="first image" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="details">
                            <p className="detailsName">{name}</p>
                            <p className="brand">{brand} </p>
                            <p className="gender">{gender}</p>
                            <p className="price">{price}€</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        })
    }
    return (
        <div className="productItem">
            {stuff}
        </div>
    )

}
```

**Views.js** call in Shop.js context doesn't work

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';


import './Views.css'

//items
import { ItemContext } from '../../../context/ItemContext'

export default function Views() {
    const [items, setItems] =  useContext(ItemContext);
    console.log(items);
    const data = items
    let stuff;
    if (data.length === 0) {
        console.log("nothing");
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        stuff = data.map((details, i) => {
            const { name, brand, gender, price, image, categorie } = details;
           
                return (
                    <div id="itemCard1">
                        <div className="itemImgWrap">
                            <img src={image} alt="first image" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="details">
                            <p className="detailsName">{name}</p>
                            <p className="brand">{brand} </p>
                            <p className="gender">{gender}</p>
                            <p className="price">{price}€</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="viewsContainer">
            <div className="viewsGrid">
                {stuff}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where you you call `setItems`? Are you clearing them when you change routes (without realizing it)? You need to show this part of your code.

Comment: Thank you @Adam. You was right the issue was that I was Navigation between pages using browser url. So Context was clearing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it by using **react-router-dom** `<Link/>`.

Given that I wanted to do the routes once my pages are initialized,
I was navigating between pages by url, so Context was always clearing and app refreshing witch is not what we want. So I used `<Link/>` and then it works because `<Link/>` help you to navigate without refreshing I guess...